# Web Project and WebService in the same application

Tags: javascript, java

The ask it's only theory

Can I developer a Java web project with one class web service ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

In Ecplise do:

> File -> New... -> Web Dynamic Project

And then you can create a WebService, depending if you want a REST service or SOAP are the next steps.. There lots of example on the web on how to create a WebService using the differents SDKs.